# Making a latex table from systemfit model?

Tags: r, latex, texreg, systemfit

**I am using systemfit to model respondents' prioritization of certain local projects. Their priorities are categorized into six categories.**

```
model1<-prior1~ fem+ party_id2 + unemployed 

model2<-prior2 ~ fem+ party_id2 + unemployed

model3<-prior3 ~ fem+ party_id2 + unemployed

model4<-prior4 ~ fem+ party_id2 + unemployed

model5<-prior5 ~ fem+ party_id2 + unemployed

model6<-prior6 ~ fem+ party_id2 + unemployed



fitsur_ind <- systemfit(list(project1 = model1, project2 = model2, project3 = model3, project4=model4, project5=model5, project6=model6), data= dat)

summary(fitsur_ind)

result1 <- texreg::extract(fitsur_ind)
```

**I want to make a Latex table where each column is a different priority (DV) but when I extract the object using texreg it extracts the coefficients for every equation. Is there a way to use texreg to extract the results separately?**

Comment: Could you please provide a ```dput``` of ```result1```? All columns to the LaTeX table are in this object?

Comment: Have you tried the argument `beside = TRUE`?

Comment: @PhilipLeifeld Yes that fixes it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In your `texreg`, `htmlreg`, `screenreg` etc. call, add the argument `beside = TRUE` to display multiple equations as separate columns. This works in some of the models, and the help pages (e.g., `?extract.systemfit` in this case) show details for the respective model implementations.